# Gitlab CE 10.x.x Omnibus installation: no "Pages" Settings pane?

Tags: configuration, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-pages

I was trying to follow the [Gitlab directions for setting up Gitlab Pages](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_three.md#add-your-custom-domain-to-gitlab-pages-settings) on my custom domain gitlab installation.  But for the specific instruction:

> navigate to your project's **Setting > Pages** and click **+ New
>   domain** to add your custom domain to GitLab Pages

there is no "Pages" entry under my Project's settings pane.  What gives?  Did they move this in newer versions of Gitlab CE?  Is the feature not available in CE (Community Edition)?

[image: Gitlab Project Settings Menu]